# Msgbox for number of rows copied to what sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, msgbox

With help from many helpful people on here I have got to the point where the code does exactly what I need it to do!

I am really struggling with the `MsgBox` at the end that display how many rows have been copied to each sheet. I would also like it to display if there were any non-matches from the Global sheet in the same `MsgBox`. If no non-matches were found then this part can be omitted.

Below is the code i have that searches the sheet for the values in `column Q` and the finds the match in the `ComboBox2` on the `UserForm`. This tells what sheet the rows need to be copied to, and if a new sheet is needed then also what to name it along with some other needed information.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, strWS As String, rngCPY As Range
  Dim noFind As Variant: noFind = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List '<~~~ get missed items
  With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .EnableEvents = False: .CutCopyMode = False: End With
  If Range("L9") = "" Then: MsgBox "You can't Split the Jobs at this stage. " & vbLf & vbLf & "Please create the form for the Sub-Contractor First." & vbLf & vbLf & "Please press Display Utilities to create form.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Operation": Exit Sub

  Dim lastG As Long: lastG = sheets("Global").Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).row
  Dim cVat As Boolean: cVat = InStr(1, sheets("Payment Form").Range("A20").value, "THE VAT SHOWN IS YOUR OUTPUT TAX DUE TO CUSTOMS AND EXCISE")

  If sheets("PAYMENT FORM").Cells(35 - cVat * 5, 12) >= 1 Then: MsgBox "It appears you have already split the jobs, this operation can only be performed once.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Operation": Exit Sub

  For j = 0 To UserForm2.ComboBox2.ListCount - 1
    noFind(j, 4) = 0
    For i = 3 To lastG
      If noFind(j, 0) = sheets("Global").Cells(i, 17) Then
        k = i
        strWS = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List(j, 1)
        On Error Resume Next  '<~~ if the worksheet in the next line does not exist, go make one
        If Len(Worksheets(strWS).Name) = 0 Then
          With ThisWorkbook
            On Error GoTo 0
            Dim nStr As String: With sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9"): nStr = Right(.value, Len(.value) - Len(Left(.value, InStr(.value, "- ")))): End With
            Dim CCName As Variant: CCName = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List(j, 2)
            Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = sheets("Payment Form").Range("U36:U53").End(xlDown).row
            Dim strRng As String: strRng = Array("A18:A34", "A23:A39")(-1 * cVat)
            Dim lastRow2 As Long: lastRow2 = sheets("Payment Form").Range(strRng).End(xlDown).row
            Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet: Set wsTemplate = ThisWorkbook.sheets("Template")
            Dim wsNew As Worksheet
            With sheets("Payment Form")
              For Each cell In .Range(strRng)
                If Len(cell) = 0 Then
                  If sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9").value = "Network" Then
                    cell.Offset.value = strWS & " - " & nStr & ": " & CCName
                  Else
                    cell.Offset.value = strWS & " -" & nStr & ": " & CCName
                  End If
                  Exit For
                End If
              Next cell
            End With
            With wsNew
            wsTemplate.Visible = True
            wsTemplate.Copy before:=sheets("Details"): Set wsNew = ActiveSheet
            wsTemplate.Visible = False
              wsNew.Name = strWS
              wsNew.Range("D4").value = sheets("Payment Form").Range(strRng).End(xlDown).value
              wsNew.Range("D6").value = sheets("Payment Form").Range("L11").value
              wsNew.Range("D8").value = sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9").value
              wsNew.Range("D10").value = sheets("Payment Form").Range("C11").value
            End With
            With .sheets("Payment Form")
              .Activate
              .Range("J" & lastRow2 + 1).value = 0
              .Range("L" & lastRow2 + 1).Formula = "=N" & lastRow2 + 1 & "-J" & lastRow2 + 1 & ""
              .Range("N" & lastRow2 + 1).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!L20"
              .Range("U" & lastRow + 1).value = strWS & ": "
              .Range("V" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!I21"
              .Range("W" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!I23"
              .Range("X" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!K21"
            End With
          End With
        End If '<~~~ end new sheet
        On Error GoTo 0
        While sheets("Global").Cells(k + 1, 17).value = noFind(j, 0) And k < lastG
          k = k + 1
        Wend
        Set rngCPY = sheets("Global").Range("Q" & i & ":Q" & k).EntireRow
        With Worksheets(strWS)
          rngCPY.Copy
          .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Insert shift:=xlDown
        End With
        noFind(j, 4) = noFind(j, 4) + k - i + 1
        i = k
      End If
    Next i
  Next j

  With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .EnableEvents = True: .CutCopyMode = True: End With

  'noFind(x, y) > x = item / y: 0 = name / y: 4 = counter
  noFind(0, 0) = noFind(0, 0) & " " & noFind(0, 4) & " times copied"
  For i = 1 To UBound(noFind)
    noFind(0, 0) = noFind(0, 0) & vbLf & noFind(i, 0) & " " & noFind(i, 4) & " times copied"
  Next
  MsgBox noFind(0, 0)
End Sub
```

This is what is currently being displayed by the `MsgBox`:

[image]

This is how I want the `MsgBox` to display the information:

[image]

I want it to show the sheet names, then how many rows have been copied to it.

Below that the total number of rows copied.

Then if required, below that display errors found on the global sheet along with how many times you found that value. I.e (BRERRORS) <- This is the cell value.

If possible below that, maybe a total number of errors found on the sheet as well.

At the very bottom, a total number of rows that were searched in the global sheet, this will be used for comparison, so if the total number of rows copied doesn't match the total number of the global sheet then the user will know they need to copied some rows manually after checking the rows value.

If it helps here is the original code without the code for the `MsgBox`, if you can think of a better way to do it.

```
Private Sub btnSplitJobs_Click()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, strWS As String, rngCPY As Range
  With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .EnableEvents = False: .CutCopyMode = False: End With
  If Range("L9") = "" Then: MsgBox "You can't Split the Jobs at this stage. " & vbLf & vbLf & "Please create the form for the Sub-Contractor First." & vbLf & vbLf & "Please press Display Utilities to create form.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Operation": Exit Sub

  Dim lastG As Long: lastG = sheets("Global").Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).row
  Dim cVat As Boolean: cVat = InStr(1, sheets("Payment Form").Range("A20").value, "THE VAT SHOWN IS YOUR OUTPUT TAX DUE TO CUSTOMS AND EXCISE")

  If sheets("PAYMENT FORM").Cells(35 - cVat * 5, 12) >= 1 Then: MsgBox "It appears you have already split the jobs, this operation can only be performed once.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Operation": Exit Sub

  For j = 0 To UserForm2.ComboBox2.ListCount - 1
    currval = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List(j, 0)
    For i = 3 To lastG
      If currval = sheets("Global").Cells(i, "Q") Then
        k = i
        strWS = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List(j, 1)
        On Error Resume Next  '<~~ if the worksheet in the next line does not exist, go make one
        If Len(Worksheets(strWS).Name) = 0 Then
          With ThisWorkbook
            On Error GoTo 0
            Dim nStr As String: With sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9"): nStr = Right(.value, Len(.value) - Len(Left(.value, InStr(.value, "- ")))): End With
            Dim CCName As Variant: CCName = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List(j, 2)
            Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = sheets("Payment Form").Range("U36:U53").End(xlDown).row
            Dim strRng As String: strRng = Array("A18:A34", "A23:A39")(-1 * cVat)
            Dim lastRow2 As Long: lastRow2 = sheets("Payment Form").Range(strRng).End(xlDown).row
            Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet: Set wsTemplate = ThisWorkbook.sheets("Template")
            Dim wsNew As Worksheet
            With sheets("Payment Form")
              For Each cell In .Range(strRng)
                If Len(cell) = 0 Then
                  If sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9").value = "Network" Then
                    cell.Offset.value = strWS & " - " & nStr & ": " & CCName
                  Else
                    cell.Offset.value = strWS & " -" & nStr & ": " & CCName
                  End If
                  Exit For
                End If
              Next cell
            End With
            With wsNew
            wsTemplate.Visible = True
            wsTemplate.Copy before:=sheets("Details"): Set wsNew = ActiveSheet
            wsTemplate.Visible = False
              wsNew.Name = strWS
              wsNew.Range("D4").value = sheets("Payment Form").Range(strRng).End(xlDown).value
              wsNew.Range("D6").value = sheets("Payment Form").Range("L11").value
              wsNew.Range("D8").value = sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9").value
              wsNew.Range("D10").value = sheets("Payment Form").Range("C11").value
            End With
            With .sheets("Payment Form")
              .Activate
              .Range("J" & lastRow2 + 1).value = 0
              .Range("L" & lastRow2 + 1).Formula = "=N" & lastRow2 + 1 & "-J" & lastRow2 + 1 & ""
              .Range("N" & lastRow2 + 1).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!L20"
              .Range("U" & lastRow + 1).value = strWS & ": "
              .Range("V" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!I21"
              .Range("W" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!I23"
              .Range("X" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!K21"
            End With
          End With
        End If '<~~~ end new sheet
        While sheets("Global").Cells(k + 1, 17).value = currval And k < lastG
          k = k + 1
        Wend
        Set rngCPY = sheets("Global").Range("Q" & i & ":Q" & k).EntireRow
        With Worksheets(strWS)
          rngCPY.Copy
          .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Insert shift:=xlDown
        End With
        i = k
      End If
    Next i
  Next j

  With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .EnableEvents = True: .CutCopyMode = True: End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have predefined list of sheet? The design of your form would not handle the situation, where number of sheets is dynamic.

Comment: @Juliusz. It depends on what you mean by predefined. The sheets are created when needed, through Userform2.combobox2 ( column 0 = code abbreviation (BRREPAIRS), column 1 = sheet name (2780), column 2 = full name (Repairs).

Comment: I would redesign that part, so there is no limit on sheet numbers and to make reporting easier - your current design can handle four sheets. I would use ListBox control (with multi column) and add new rows to it. (Short of time right now, sorry for being very vague)

Comment: @Juliusz. There is no limit on the number of sheets allowed, they are set to the combobox as all the sheets that could possible be used at the current time, if a new sheet is needed that is not in the list, then the user will create it manually, then i will update the combobox to include it for the future.